# On click show / hide content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with javascript show/hide content from div. When I click on the first button I got content from that but when I click on the second I need to hide content from first and show content from second div. My code for this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function showHideDiv(ele) {
                var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);
                if (srcElement != null) {
                    if (srcElement.style.display == "block") {
                        srcElement.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else {
                        srcElement.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function showHideDiv1(ele) {
                var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);
                if (srcElement != null) {
                    if (srcElement.style.display == "block") {
                        srcElement.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else {
                        srcElement.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="listsearch-header fl-wrap">
<h3>
<a class="button-one" onClick="showHideDiv('divMsg')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Places</a>
<a class="button-two" onClick="showHideDiv1('divMsg1')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Events</a>
</h3>
<div id="divMsg" style=" display:none">
<b>Places</b>
</div>
<div id="divMsg1" style="display:none">
<b>Events</b>
</div>
</div>
```

How to solve this when clicking on second button to hide content from the first button. Thanks, all

Comment: I think this link help with you http://jsfiddle.net/tqhHA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with toggle the class based on clicked element

```js
function showHideDiv(ele) {
  var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);
  document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(a => a.classList.add('hide'))
  if (srcElement != null) {
    srcElement.classList.toggle('hide')
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="listsearch-header fl-wrap">
  <h3>
    <a class="button-one" onClick="showHideDiv('divMsg')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Places</a>
    <a class="button-two" onClick="showHideDiv('divMsg1')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Events</a>
  </h3>
  <div id="divMsg" class="box hide">
    <b>Places</b>
  </div>
  <div id="divMsg1" class="box hide">
    <b>Events</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a problem with this code. Content from Places shows, but when click on Events don't show.

Comment: you can add the class attribute in html. see my html and css

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic function which takes the actual elements to be shown or hidden as input parameters.

```js
function showHideDiv(show, hide) {
  document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(hide).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="listsearch-header fl-wrap">
  <h3>
    <a class="button-one" onClick="showHideDiv('divMsg','divMsg1')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Places</a>
    <a class="button-two" onClick="showHideDiv('divMsg1','divMsg')" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Events</a>
  </h3>
  <div id="divMsg" style=" display:none">
    <b>Places</b>
  </div>
  <div id="divMsg1" style="display:none">
    <b>Events</b>
  </div>
</div>
```